# What is the moment of inertia of a cylinder about a skew axis?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Suppose that there is a cylinder of uniform density with radius  $ r $ , height  $ h $ and mass $M$.

An axis  $ \ell $  is chosen through its geometric center making an angle  $ \theta $  with the horizontal.

What is the cylinder's moment of inertia about $\ell$?

Is it possible to do this by using the rotation of axes formulae?

Comment: MMOI transforms according to the congruent transformation rules $$ \mathbf{I}_{\rm new} = \mathrm{R} \mathbf{I}_{\rm old} \mathrm{R}^\top$$

Answer (score 2):

If the skew axis makes angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ with the $x, y, z$ axes respectively then the moment of inertia about this axis for any rigid body is
$$I=I_{xx}\cos^2\alpha+I_{yy}\cos^2\beta+I_{zz}\cos^2\gamma-2I_{xy}\cos\alpha \cos\beta -2I_{yz}\cos\beta \cos\gamma -2I_{zx}\cos\gamma \cos\alpha$$

Here $I_{xx}=\int \rho x^2 dV$ etc are the moments of inertia about the $x, y, z$ axes and $I_{xy}=I_{yx}=\int \rho xy dV$ etc are **products of inertia**.

Note that $\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma$ are *direction cosines* so that  $\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1$. They are related to spherical polar angles by
$$\cos\alpha=\cos\theta \sin\phi, \space \cos\beta=\sin\theta \sin\phi, \space \cos\gamma=\cos\phi$$

The products of inertia $I_{xy}$ etc vanish for 3 particular mutually orthogonal axes through the centre of mass called the **principal axes**. These axes can be identified practically because no torque is required when the body is rotating about such an axis; the rotation is dynamically balanced. Geometrically they can often be identified as axes of symmetry.

Mathematically the principal axes and their moments of inertia can be found by diagonalising the **inertia matrix/tensor** formed by the elements $I_{xx}, I_{xy}, I_{xz}$ etc.

---

With the origin at the CM of the cylinder, and $Ox$ along its axis, then all 3 planes $Oxy, Oyz, Ozx $ are planes of symmetry, with the result that $I_{xy}=I_{yz}=I_{zx}=0$.

The cylinder is an elongated disk so $I_{xx}=\frac12 MR^2$. If the cylinder were a planar disk ($H\ll R$) then $I_{yy}=I_{zz}=\frac12 I_{xx}=\frac14 MR^2$, whereas if it were a rod ($H \gg R$) then $I_{yy}=I_{zz}=\frac{1}{12} MH^2$. Combining both forms we get $I_{yy}=I_{zz}=\frac{1}{12} M(3R^2+H^2)$.

If we were to take an axis through the rim of the cylinder (still passing though the centre of mass) then $\tan\alpha=\frac{R}{H}$. With a suitable choice of $y, z$ axes we get $\beta=0$ and $\gamma=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$ so that $\cos\gamma=\sin\alpha$. It would make no difference if we chose the $y, z$ axes differently.

---

Reference : [Chapter 2: Centroids and Moments of Inertia](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461434740-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1332156-p174306965) in *Advanced Dynamics : Analytical and Numerical Calculations with MATLAB* by Marghitu and Dupac, Springer Science.